# Is there a well known algorithm for this use case (similar to semaphore)?

Tags: c#, algorithm, go

I have a use case where multiple clients need a shared resource. The amount of shared resources is represented with an integer `available`. `available` is decremented by N (when some resources are taken), and incremented by N (when those resources is returned).

If a caller requests N resources, but `available` is less than N, the function needs to block until another client(s) return enough resources such that `available` is now sufficient (>= `N`).

I was looking into semaphores, but it seems they can only be incremented / decremented by 1 (I need `N`). Rate limiting algorithms like token bucket also don't fit my use case since that is based on a time interval, mine is more of a signal when resource is returned.

Is there any well known algorithm for this? It's not language specific but if C# or Go has classes that support this then those answers are welcome.

Comment: This just sounds like a queue? You have a set of homogenous resources, and a queue of jobs. Jobs wait in the queue until the resources for that job are available, and then they run.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yeah it is a queue. Perhaps I need a queue whose elements are `(requiredResources, EventWaitHandle)` and signal the first element's wait handle when `available` >= `requiredResources`. Need to do more brainstorming but I wanted to see if there was a well known algorithm for this rather than hacking together something myself.

Comment: I was going to suggest "condition variable" before the answer was closed.

Comment: It sounds like you just need a resourceManager that keeps track of available resources. When a resource becomes available, it notifies the manager, and the manager checks if the next item in the queue is available. This seems too basic to qualify as "an algorithm"